# Starting one Spring Boot Application by using SoapUITestCaseRunner?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soapui

I am interested if it is there a way to start a Spring Boot Application from within a class that extends the SoapUITestCaseRunner by using any kind of configuration in the beforeRun() method.

Comment: What are you trying to do more exactly? run a sopaui project from spring boot? And in the `beforeRun()` you want to configure the soapui project or something else. Please provide more context to your question `:)`

Comment: I want to start a simulator class along with the main class in the class that starts the Integration Tests

Comment: Can you share the spring-boot base code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start some other application from with soapui, then you can add the logic inside of `Setup script` of the project.

Open your soapui project -> double click on the project -> go to Test Suites tab. `Setup Script` button is available in the bottom.

Add the business logic to start your Spring Boot application into `Setup Script`(shown in the below screen shot) which will be executed before running any of the test suites.

[image]

And you may also use `TearDown Script` to shut down the application.

Based on the comment, below is the update:

Looks user wants to run the soapui project from within his/her own application.

Below is the `java` code snippet to do so, which is taken from SoapUI's [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/junit/junit-integration.html).

```
SoapUITestCaseRunner runner = new SoapUITestCaseRunner();
//Change project path to suit your environment
runner.setProjectFile("/absolute/path/to/soapui-project.xml");
runner.setPrintReport(true); 
runner.run();
```

Comment: I was actually interested in starting the class from within the Java Project, not the Soap UI program.

Comment: The question does not seem to clarify that. Any ways, You can call `SoapUITestCaseRunner`, which can run the soapui project, from your application as well if you want that way.

Comment: @miha1908, please check the updated answer to see if that is more of what you are looking for? Otherwise, please edit your question and clarify what is the exact details.